# Secure Enclave: update SecAccessControlCreateFlags after key creation

Tags: ios, swift, enclave

I am wondering if anyone knows whether its possible to update the flags **after** the key creation inside the **Secure Enclave** or not?
Here's how I am creating the key:

```
let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
                                             [SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence, 
                                              SecAccessControlCreateFlags.privateKeyUsage],
                                              nil)!
let attributes: [String: Any] = [
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 256,
    kSecAttrTokenID as String: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String: [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: "stacksometimesoverflow",
        kSecAttrAccessControl as String: access
    ]
]

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
guard SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error) != nil else {
    throw error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error
}
```

As you can see, the key is created with

```
SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.privateKeyUsage
```

My question is, is it possible to update the access flag of the key (**same key**), say I want to remove **SecAccessControlCreateFlags.userPresence**

All the best!

Johnny

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave):

> ... because its backing storage is physically part of the Secure Enclave, you can never inspect the key’s data.

I think the best way is to delete your key with `SecItemDelete(_:)` and then create new key without the `.userPresence` flag.